# Why is this widget positioned on top of the menu-bar?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyside

When I run the following example, I expect the QListWidget to be positioned below the menubar, but in fact it positions on top of the menubar. The menubar is still present, as can be confirmed by using the Alt-F shortcut to open it.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        menubar = self.menuBar()

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('appication-exit'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        QListWidget(self)

    def run(self):
        self.show()
        app.exec_()

MainWindow().run()
```

The result:

[image: Resulting window]

I was not able to fix this problem by using a `QVBoxLayout` (I tried both adding the menubar to the `QVBoxLayout` and not adding it).

I'm running pyqt 4.11.4, qt 4.8.7, pyside 1.2.4, and Python 3.5.

Any ideas on how to correctly position the QListWidget?

Comment: Great! If you put that as an answer I can mark this as answered.

Comment: Not about the question. PyQt and PySide are modules for the same purpose. You just select one installed. For this app, python and PySide are enough. pyqt and qt are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either:

```
self.setCentralWidget(QListWidget(self))
```

Or:

```
widget = QWidget(self)
layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
layout.addWidget(QListWidget(self))
self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

The latter is probably better, since you will no doubt want to add more widgets.